# Facebook: GLOBAL_URL -> APP_SCOPED_ID?

Tags: facebook, api, url

Is there any way to get the APP_SCOPED_ID from a global url of a user (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/zuck)?
My service needs to proof that the global url belongs to the user logging in to my app through oauth. Unfortunately I only get an APP_SCOPED_ID and APP SCOPED URL in the form of http://fb.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app_scoped_user_id}. Using traceroute seems to hacky and the backend would need to be logged in to facebook. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: _“My service needs to proof that the global url belongs to the user logging in to my app through oauth”_ - why, what for?

Comment: I want my users to be able to send "things" to other users through my app using their global url as identifier. These other users are then notified and can claim these "things" when they log in to my app. Part of my app uses a Chrome extention. The extention should not need to log in anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get the App Scoped ID from the global URL or the global ID - and vice versa.